# How to do some task after Asterisk ReceiveFax function calling?

Tags: linux, asterisk, voip, fax, telecommunication

I have asterisk Server installed:
And I have created Dial-plan for Receive Fax:
I want to do some task after successfully received fax. but, any line written after `ReceveFax` function ONLY called when Transmission is **FAILED**. If transmission is **SUCCESS** will never called any line after.

> **My Dial-Plan:**

```
;######################### FAX Dialplan Implementation Start ##########################

exten => _15555551212,1,NoOp(Fax receiving from ${EXTEN})
exten => _15555551212,n,Answer
exten => _15555551212,n,Ringing
exten => _15555551212,n,Macro(inboundfax)
exten => _15555551212,n,NoOp(Done)

exten => h,1, NoOp(Completed...)

[macro-inboundfax]
exten => s,1,NoOp(**** FAX RECEIVED from ${CALLERID(num)} ${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%c)} ****)
exten => s,n,Set(FAXOPT(ecm)=yes)
exten => s,n,Set(FILENAME=fax-${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)})
exten => s,n,Set(FAXFILE=${FILENAME}.tif)
exten => s,n,Set(FAXOPT(ecm)=yes)
exten => s,n,Set(FAXOPT(headerinfo)=Received by MYCOMPANY ${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M)})
exten => s,n,Set(FAXOPT(localstationid)=5555551212)
exten => s,n,Set(FAXOPT(maxrate)=14400)
exten => s,n,Set(FAXOPT(minrate)=4800)
exten => s,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(ecm) : ${FAXOPT(ecm)})
exten => s,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(headerinfo) : ${FAXOPT(headerinfo)})
exten => s,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(localstationid) : ${FAXOPT(localstationid)})
exten => s,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(maxrate) : ${FAXOPT(maxrate)})
exten => s,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(minrate) : ${FAXOPT(minrate)})
exten => s,n,NoOp(**** RECEIVING FAX : ${FAXFILE} ****)
exten => s,n,Set(FAX_DEST=/var/www/html/private/fax/received)
exten => s,n,Set(FAXDEST=/tmp)

exten => s,n,DumpChan(3)

exten => s,n,ReceiveFAX(${FAXDEST}/${FAXFILE})
exten => s,n,Verbose(3,- Fax receipt completed with status: ${FAXSTATUS})

exten => s,n,Verbose(Fax receipt completed with status: ${FAXSTATUS})

exten => s,n,Verbose(FaxFile moving... ${FAXDEST}/${FAXFILE} -> ${FAX_DEST}/)
exten => s,n,System(mv ${FAXDEST}/${FAXFILE} ${FAX_DEST}/)
exten => s,n,Verbose(Fax file moved.)

exten => s,n,NoOp(Mail Sending...)
;exten => s,n,System(echo | mutt -a ${FAXDEST}/${FAXFILE} -s "received fax" testfax@gmail.com)
exten => s,n,NoOp(Mail Sent)
```

Console Log: (While Receiving Fax)

```
 == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [15555551212@from-sip:1] NoOp("SIP/4001-0000000f", "Fax receiving from 15555551212") in new stack
    -- Executing [15555551212@from-sip:2] Answer("SIP/4001-0000000f", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [15555551212@from-sip:3] Ringing("SIP/4001-0000000f", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [15555551212@from-sip:4] Macro("SIP/4001-0000000f", "inboundfax") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:1] NoOp("SIP/4001-0000000f", "**** FAX RECEIVED from 4001 Sat Jun 20 15:25:22 2015 ****") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:2] Set("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FAXOPT(ecm)=yes") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:3] Set("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FILENAME=fax-20150620-152522") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:4] Set("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FAXFILE=fax-20150620-152522.tif") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:5] Set("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FAXOPT(ecm)=yes") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:6] Set("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FAXOPT(headerinfo)=Received by MYCOMPANY 2015-06-20 15:25") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:7] Set("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FAXOPT(localstationid)=5555551212") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:8] Set("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FAXOPT(maxrate)=14400") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:9] Set("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FAXOPT(minrate)=4800") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:10] NoOp("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FAXOPT(ecm) : yes") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:11] NoOp("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FAXOPT(headerinfo) : Received by MYCOMPANY 2015-06-20 15:25") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:12] NoOp("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FAXOPT(localstationid) : 5555551212") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:13] NoOp("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FAXOPT(maxrate) : 14400") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:14] NoOp("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FAXOPT(minrate) : 4800") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:15] NoOp("SIP/4001-0000000f", "**** RECEIVING FAX : fax-20150620-152522.tif ****") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:16] Set("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FAX_DEST=/var/www/html/private/fax/received") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:17] Set("SIP/4001-0000000f", "FAXDEST=/tmp") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:18] DumpChan("SIP/4001-0000000f", "3") in new stack
    --
    -- Dumping Info For Channel: SIP/4001-0000000f:
    -- ================================================================================
    -- Info:
    -- Name=               SIP/4001-0000000f
    -- Type=               SIP
    -- UniqueID=           1434794122.15
    -- LinkedID=           1434794122.15
    -- CallerIDNum=        4001
    -- CallerIDName=       FaxVoip SoftPhone
    -- ConnectedLineIDNum= (N/A)
    -- ConnectedLineIDName=(N/A)
    -- DNIDDigits=         15555551212
    -- RDNIS=              (N/A)
    -- Parkinglot=         default
    -- Language=           en
    -- State=              Up (6)
    -- Rings=              0
    -- NativeFormat=       (ulaw)
    -- WriteFormat=        slin
    -- ReadFormat=         ulaw
    -- RawWriteFormat=     ulaw
    -- RawReadFormat=      ulaw
    -- WriteTranscode=     Yes (slin)->(ulaw)
    -- ReadTranscode=      No
    -- 1stFileDescriptor=  26
    -- Framesin=           1
    -- Framesout=          0
    -- TimetoHangup=       0
    -- ElapsedTime=        0h0m0s
    -- DirectBridge=       <none>
    -- IndirectBridge=     <none>
    -- Context=            macro-inboundfax
    -- Extension=          s
    -- Priority=           18
    -- CallGroup=
    -- PickupGroup=
    -- Application=        DumpChan
    -- Data=               3
    -- Blocking_in=        (Not Blocking)
    --
    -- Variables:
    -- MACRO_DEPTH=1
    -- FAXDEST=/tmp
    -- FAX_DEST=/var/www/html/private/fax/received
    -- FAXFILE=fax-20150620-152522.tif
    -- FILENAME=fax-20150620-152522
    -- MACRO_PRIORITY=4
    -- MACRO_CONTEXT=from-sip
    -- MACRO_EXTEN=15555551212
    -- SIPCALLID=af6dfc5a-ee0f-1910-9de1-e06995d7f913@dsk-388
    -- SIPDOMAIN=XX.XX.XX.XX
    -- SIPURI=sip:4001@XX.XX.XX.XX:5065
    -- ================================================================================
    -- Executing [s@macro-inboundfax:19] ReceiveFAX("SIP/4001-0000000f", "/tmp/fax-20150620-152522.tif") in new stack
    -- Channel 'SIP/4001-0000000f' receiving FAX '/tmp/fax-20150620-152522.tif'
  == Using UDPTL CoS mark 5
    -- Channel 'SIP/4001-0000000f' FAX session '5' started
    -- FAX handle 0: [ 026.931800 ], entering CLOSING state
    -- FAX handle 0: [ 026.931866 ], entering CLOSING state
    -- Channel 'SIP/4001-0000000f' FAX session '5' is complete, result: 'SUCCESS' (FAX_SUCCESS), error: 'NO_ERROR', pages: 2, resolution: '204x98', transfer rate: '14400', remoteSID: ''
  == Spawn extension (macro-inboundfax, s, 19) exited non-zero on 'SIP/4001-0000000f' in macro 'inboundfax'
  == Spawn extension (from-sip, 15555551212, 4) exited non-zero on 'SIP/4001-0000000f'
```

Comment: You can use h extension to perform any task after receiving fax. `exten => h,1,NoOp(FaxStatus : ${FAXSTATUS})` .For complex process I would suggest to use AGI in 'h' extension (eg. updating database, converting file format etc.)

Comment: right, May be this will useful, But is there any changes required as in my case Dial-plan is break after successfully received Fax, Nothing is called.

Should It required any changes in above dialplan.

Comment: Are you able to achieve `exten => h,1, NoOp(Completed...)` this level when you receive fax successfully ?

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea already ... put all your "after fax" processing here:

```
exten => h,1, NoOp(Completed...)
```

Since the `${FAXSTATUS}` variable is a channel global, it persists until the end of the `h` extension processing.  `if ... then` process based on it's status.

Comment: If I got ${FAXSTATUS} === success, after I want to call my AGI Script which will handle my Web Service and Send URL for FAX File.

Is it delayed saved or saved if I got success message.

Comment: Also make sure add hangup line just after the ReceiveFAX line for safety.

Answer (score 2):

```html
[fax-rx]
exten => _X.,1,Ringing()
exten => _X.,n,Answer()
exten => _X.,n,wait(10)
exten => fax,1,Verbose(got a Fax on ${EXTEN})
exten => fax,n,NoOp(**** FAX RECEIVE ****)
exten => fax,n,Set(GLOBAL(FAXCOUNT)=$[ ${GLOBAL(FAXCOUNT)} + 1 ])
exten => fax,n,Set(FAXCOUNT=${GLOBAL(FAXCOUNT)})
exten => fax,n,Set(FAXFILE=fax-${FAXCOUNT}-rx.tif)
exten => fax,n,Set(GLOBAL(LASTFAXCALLERNUM)=${CALLERID(num)})
exten => fax,n,Set(GLOBAL(LASTFAXCALLERNAME)=${CALLERID(name)})
exten => fax,n,NoOp(**** SETTING FAXOPT ****)
exten => fax,n,Set(FAXOPT(ecm)=yes)
exten => fax,n,Set(FAXOPT(headerinfo)=MY FAXBACK RX)
exten => fax,n,Set(FAXOPT(localstationid)=1234567890)
exten => fax,n,Set(FAXOPT(maxrate)=14400)
exten => fax,n,Set(FAXOPT(minrate)=2400)
exten => fax,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(ecm) : ${FAXOPT(ecm)})
exten => fax,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(headerinfo) : ${FAXOPT(headerinfo)})
exten => fax,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(localstationid) : ${FAXOPT(localstationid)})
exten => fax,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(maxrate) : ${FAXOPT(maxrate)})
exten => fax,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(minrate) : ${FAXOPT(minrate)})
exten => fax,n,NoOp(**** RECEIVING FAX : ${FAXFILE} ****)
exten => fax,n,ReceiveFAX(/var/spool/asterisk/fax/${FAXFILE})
; Hangup! Print FAXOPTs
exten => h,1,NoOp(FAXOPT(ecm) : ${FAXOPT(ecm)})
exten => h,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(filename) : ${FAXOPT(filename)})
exten => h,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(headerinfo) : ${FAXOPT(headerinfo)})
exten => h,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(localstationid) : ${FAXOPT(localstationid)})
exten => h,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(maxrate) : ${FAXOPT(maxrate)})
exten => h,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(minrate) : ${FAXOPT(minrate)})
exten => h,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(pages) : ${FAXOPT(pages)})
exten => h,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(rate) : ${FAXOPT(rate)})
exten => h,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(remotestationid) : ${FAXOPT(remotestationid)})
exten => h,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(resolution) : ${FAXOPT(resolution)})
exten => h,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(status) : ${FAXOPT(status)})
exten => h,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(statusstr) : ${FAXOPT(statusstr)})
exten => h,n,NoOp(FAXOPT(error) : ${FAXOPT(error)})
```

Comment: Great, If file was received by Fax, I am storing it in `/tmp` Location. Should I changed it to different location? As I have changed but, It will not store and give some error. for that In my Dial-plan I have put `mv` command to move file to another location.

Comment: above code looks great, I will configure some of the things and test.

Comment: You can change the location as you required. But before doing it just check the directory permission, Also If this answer helped you then please consider this as the right answer.

Comment: I will do, Can you let me know when asterisk created file and I am trying to move in full permissioned directory it will not move/copy. anything should I do.

Comment: First of all, You check whether you are receiving the fax file properly or not, If you are able receive fax in your mentioned directories, then move the received file to the permissible directories in which you are required to put the file.If you are not able to move that file then print the error which you receive while moving the file. Try to debug by finding that error.

Comment: File moved success, Using PHP-AGI Script and system() function of PHP, I have moved/copied file to my desire place and I realized that File has user = asterisk and group = asterisk. If I set that file to root:root still I can not download. Is it required any special permission